.gitignore not to ignore a certain file name in ignored subfolders
My project has many (currently 2) subfolders with name .vscode/ and I need my .gitignore to ignore that subfolders and all its files, excepting the one called launch.json
My .gitignore is like this
.vscode
.vscode/
.vscode/*
**/.vscode/*
**/.vscode
!.vscode/launch.json

It is correctly ignoring all .vscode subfolders and files, I have worked with this for many days/commits. But now I want to use the ! operator in order to let all launch.json files inside of that folders to be version controlled, and it is not working, when I make changes in any of the launch.json files Git continues not detect changes.

Just keep the rules to ignore and force-add the file.... once the file is tracked, it doesn't matter if a rule in .gitignore matches it, it won't be ignored anymore.

Any way of force-adding all my launch.json files instead of adding 1 by 1? And how is that command?

with a find? find ./ -name whatever-you-need --exec git add -f {} ';'

It's -exec (single dash), not --exec, by the way.

The .gitignore file is parsed from top to bottom, so you have to declare first the exclusions, like follow:
!.vscode/launch.json
.vscode
.vscode/
.vscode/*
**/.vscode/*
**/.vscode

